# Different combobox choices change listbox & label content

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, listbox

I am creating a program where when the user has chosen something from the combobox, it will update the listbox and then after the user has *selected* one of the provided choices in listbox, the label next to it will pretty much show the description of that selected item.

Here's a picture of the interface to give you a better idea: 
[image]

So far I came up with this code:

```
  public MainHub()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listbox1.DataSource = choices;
            listbox1.DisplayMember = name;
        }

        private void listbox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            description_label.Text = valikud.ElementAt(listbox1.SelectedIndex).description;

        }

        List<dynamic> choices = new List<dynamic>()
        {

            new
            {
                name = "Name1",
                desciption = "Description1"
            },

            new
            {
                name = "Name2",
                desciption = "Description2"
            }

        };    
    }
}
```

This just adds a *name* to the listbox and attaches a description with it.

How can I make it so that when an item is chosen in the combobox, the listbox will update, add the declared items, and then the declared listbox items will each have their own description?

I attempted to do this with the `if` statement but to no luck

-Thanks!

Comment: From your description it appears to be missing how is the combo box filled? Your comment: _How can I make it so that when an item is chosen in the combo box, the list box will update, add the declared items, and then the declared listbox items will each have their own description?_ … this is easily done. It would help if you showed how the data is stored as this will determine how to accomplish this. Is this data coming from one data table? What do you want the combo box to display and if “x” is displayed then what “y” or “z” do you want displayed elsewhere?

Comment: You may want to peruse… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As I mentioned _This code just adds a name to the listbox and attaches a description with it._ Presumably the combobox could be filled with a sublist is my theory which i can't seem to replicate with my knowledge, everything is in the post, there are no databases/data tables.
I mentioned in my first sentance _when the user has chosen something from the combobox_  this **something** can be a category for e.g. when the user has chosen a Certain category the listbox below it will display an assortment of programs, when selecting one program the label next to it will display the description.

Comment: So basically in the posted code you have simply added some text to a list box. But really you want to use this list box to display something that is related to what is selected in the combo box? Again this is relatively easy depending on how your data is stored. You question is very broad in this context. There are many ways to accomplish this... what have you tried other than the code above that does nothing to accomplish what you are asking. Try something and if doesn't work post a new or edit this question.

Comment: The code represented in the post adds text into the listbox and when one of the chosen text's have been selected there will display a description in the label next to the listbox, each _text_ aka choice has a different description, I added this to show what I have come up so far and to give others an idea of what I wish to do, saying "_this is relatively easy_" is uncalled for, there are many ways of coding anything, how is this broad? There is an problem and an objective, I'm not asking for a novel of ways of doing this just an example, i mentioned already how I tried to do this in the post.

Comment: I am not asking you to tell me if this problem is _difficult_ or not, I am asking for a professional point of view and understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i think it can be done. I haven't tested it because i can not do it now and i wrote it from my head. I will test it afternoon but until then you can figure it out yourself if i made something wrong (also comment and i will give answer until i test it)

So here is the code:

```
public class MainHub
{
    List<List_Category> category = new List<List_Category>();
    List<Items> items = new List<Items>();

    public MainHub()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        category.Add(new List_Category { CategoryIndex = 0, CategoryName = "Swords" }); // Add some category
        category.Add(new List_Category { CategoryIndex = 1, CategoryName = "Shields" }); // Add some category

        items.Add(new Items { CategoryIndex = 0, ItemName = "Long sword", ItemDesc = "Long sword is heavy sword with pure force" }); //Add some item to swords
        items.Add(new Items { CategoryIndex = 0, ItemName = "Short sword", ItemDesc = "Short sword is easy sword for close range fight" }); //Add some item to swords
        items.Add(new Items { CategoryIndex = 0, ItemName = "Double swords", ItemDesc = "Double swords are swords with hight mobility" }); //Add some item to swords

        items.Add(new Items { CategoryIndex = 1, ItemName = "Light shield", ItemDesc = "Light shield desc" }); //Add some item to shields
        items.Add(new Items { CategoryIndex = 1, ItemName = "Heavy shield", ItemDesc = "Heavy shield desc" }); //Add some item to shields

        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CategoryIndex";

        comboBox1.DataSource = category;

        listBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "CategoryIndex";

        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Items> tempItems = new List<Items>();
        switch (Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue))
        {
            case 0:
                var item = items.Where(cat => cat.CategoryIndex == 0);

                foreach (var i in item)
                {
                    tempItems.Add(new Items { CategoryIndex = i.CategoryIndex, ItemDesc = i.ItemDesc, ItemName = i.ItemName });
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                item = items.Where(cat => cat.CategoryIndex == 1);

                foreach (var i in item)
                {
                    tempItems.Add(new Items { CategoryIndex = i.CategoryIndex, ItemDesc = i.ItemDesc, ItemName = i.ItemName });
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        listBox1.DataSource = tempItems;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var asd = listBox1.SelectedItem as Items;
        if (asd != null)
        {
            name_Label.Text = asd.ItemName;
            description_label.Text = asd.ItemDesc;
        }
    }
}


public class List_Category
{
    public int CategoryIndex { get; set; }
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public int CategoryIndex { get; set; }
    public String ItemName { get; set; }
    public String ItemDesc { get; set; }
}
```

It can be optimized but as i said i can not do it right now so try something yourself. If i made some mistake or some error pops up, comment and i will answer.

Comment: There seems to be an error at `switch(combobox1.SelectedValue)` stating that it has to be a _bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type_ . 
And theres an error at `category.CategoryIndex == listBox1.SelectedValue` which says _Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'object'_

Comment: @Winter i have edited and tested code. It is working now. Solution for second problem was simple and you could do it yourself and first problem was little problem but i did it without LINQ. Try this code now, it is working.